# Display string containing HTML tag in Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, href, angularjs-ng-href

I checked for answers in SO but couldn't find satisfying answer. So here I'm asking :

I have a string as follow

```
var string = "With this you have agreed with the <a href='#'>rules and condition</a>"
```

Which I need to render as both string (for the text portion) and HTML (for the HTML portion).

How do I achieve this in **AngularJs**? I tried with `$compile` but it didn't work for me, it output chunks of seemingly minified code on the page.

Comment: Given working sample below, please refer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using ng-bind-html,

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('foo', function($scope) {
    $scope.bar = "With this you have agreed with the <a href='#'>rules and condition</a>";
});

<div ng-controller="foo">    
    <div ng-bind-html="bar"></div>    
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tbutbap3/3/)**

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ng-bind-html` directive as below. To use this, you have to include `ngSanitize` module and related js file.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
  $scope.string = 'With this you have agreed with the <a href="#">rules and condition</a>';
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="TestController">
  <span ng-bind-html="string"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
    <div
      ng-bind-html="myHTML">
    ...
    </div>
<html>
```

Ng Code :

```
angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.myHTML =
         'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
         '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>';
    }]);
```

Download sanitize.js from [here](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize/blob/master/angular-sanitize.min.js)

Answer (score 1):

#### AngularJS

```
$scope.string = "With this you have agreed with the <a href='#'>rules and condition</a>"
```

#### HTML

```
<div ng-bind-html="string"> </div>
```